# Set field pattern if pattern is defined?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object node in my scope called pattern. If it's set, I would like to add the pattern to the DOM as a pattern-attribute for an input-field. I attempted this:

```
{{field.pattern && 'pattern='+field.pattern}}
```

this works if I put it as content in a `<p>`-tag for example, but when I try to put it inside an input-node, it says my controller got undefined: `Argument 'Invite' is not a function, got undefined`

I also found this

```
ng-attr-pattern="{{field.pattern && field.pattern}}"
```

however, this adds an empty pattern-attribute if pattern is undefined, this makes the form invalid.

Comment: This doesn't provide enough of a sample to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-pattern` instead, along with a default pattern:

**Javascript**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.pattern1 = /^[0-9]+$/;

  $scope.getFooPattern = function() {
    return $scope.pattern1 || /.*/;
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo" name="foo" ng-pattern="getFooPattern()">
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22ruw/) example.

Comment: I was going to say this wouldn't work if the `type="email"` and the `pattern="/.*/"` but it looks like that's not true, it simply adds another `ng-valid-pattern` class to your input. This is a work around to the real problem, but it works none-the-less...